# set sender name and last name when sending mail with Gmail API

Tags: python, email, gmail, gmail-api

How do you set sender Name and Last name when sending mail via gmail API?

I use this code: https://github.com/chris-brown-nz/python-gmail-api

The code is great and I successfully send mail. However, the name of sender is just the text left from `@` sign. example: if `John Travis` send email from `johnhomeboy@gmail.com` the name that appears on the receiver side would be `johnhomeboy`, instead of `John Travis`. What property do I need to set in order to send emails with my name and last name?

Comment: Assuming the gmail API accepts standard RFC822 formats then presumably you can set the `to_address = 'John Travis <johnhomeboy@gmail.com>'`.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: for me the key for the mail option is from, not to_address. Apart of that it works in ruby with the desired display name in front of the email address.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments by AChampion, gmail API accepts standard RFC822 formats so, using Gmail Python APIs sending from a email `user@example.com`

```
create_message('user@example.com', 'DESTINATION_EMAIL', 'TITLE', 'BODY')
```

Sender name can be customised with

```
create_message("CUSTOMTISED_FROM_TITLE '<user@example.com>'", 'DESTINATION_EMAIL', 'TITLE', 'BODY')
```

Where `create_message` is defined as

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Following the example at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending?authuser=2